# How to hide an html element before click button (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

Example this is my content

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/H76_oByaDZk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    Game of Thrones S7 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

My code is working ,  click button then loading iframe but i want to hide my iframe an html element .

this is my single.php

```
$id = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
$text = the_content_devturkeli('<p class="serif">Full Text &raquo;</p>'); 
$last = preg_replace('^<iframe(.*?)></iframe>^', '<a href="#" onclick="showBlock(\'' . $id . '\')">Click To Watch</a> <div style="display: none;" id="' . $id . '"><embed\\1>\\2</embed><a href="#" onclick="hideBlock(\'' . $id . '\')"> Hide</a></div>', $text);
unset($id);
echo $last;
```

The video loading after click button , but i can not hide html source code

I tried a lot but i dont know how to do it . When you answering this question please tell me where should i add your code (function.php or smt) cause many times the website doesnt work when i add code . Have a good day .

Also i changed those

wp-includes/post-template.php

```
function the_content_devturkeli($more_link_text = null, $stripteaser = 0, $more_file = '') {
         $content = get_the_content($more_link_text, $stripteaser, $more_file);
         $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
         $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
         return $content;
}
```

And header.php

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function showBlock(blockId) { 
    document.getElementById(blockId).style.display = "block"; 
} 
function hideBlock(blockId) { 
    document.getElementById(blockId).style.display = "none"; 
} 
</script>
```

Which part should i edit those . I want to hide html source code until clicked

this part from content not all content .

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/H76_oByaDZk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: from your code , what would like to echo in echo $last; ?

Comment: content (iframe and text) but i dont want to show iframe code html source code until clicked button .

Answer (score 0):

To hide the result html source code until clicked your desired button you need to use ajax. So in your button click function call your ajax and from that ajax call return your desired html code(iframe code in your case) and put that code in your html (using jQuery you can use html(returned_iframe_code), append(returned_iframe_code) or prepend(returned_iframe_code) etc. function) or javascript.

I am not providing you any code as you can implement the ajax code many way as you like. This is the idea you can achieve your requirements.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried but I couldn't , i dont know how to use ajax in wordpress and how to  integrate my code I am searching almost 1 month but i just find ajax load content on home page like load more button or infinitive scroll